# Encrypt a big file using openssl smime

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, smime

I have generated a local certificate in my system and I am trying to encrypt a file through smime. But when I run the command it give me error `Unable to load certificate Expecting trusted certificate Error 1024`. This is my script that I am trying to run

```
openssl  smime  -encrypt -aes256  -in  ABC.xml  -binary  -outform DEM  -out  DEF.xml  test.pem
```

`Test.pem` is my public key. Can anyone tell me that how can I bypass this section and generate a file. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you create your `test.pem`?

Answer (score 12):

You don't indicate how you created your `test.pem`, but here's the sequence of commands you might be able to use:

Create a new key and a certificate request (you will be prompted for additional information to complete the request):

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privkey.pem -out req.pem
```

Self-sign the certificate request to create a certificate

```
openssl x509 -req -in req.pem -signkey privkey.pem -out cert.pem
```

(You can delete `req.pem` at this point if you wish)

Encrypt the file using the newly generated certificate:

```
openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in ABC.xml -binary -outform DER -out DEF.xml cert.pem
```

The file can then be decrypted using:

```
openssl smime -decrypt -in DEF.xml -inform DER -inkey privkey.pem -out GHI.xml
```

Comment: I am trying to run the first command but it is saying unable to load openssl.conf

Comment: @user2216168 You can add a `-config path/to/openssl.conf` parameter to direct it to a valid `openssl.conf`. Your openssl installation should contain a sample version of this file (in the `ssl` sub-directory) which you can use as-is or modify to your needs.